# WordPress get_query_var( 'view-order' ) returns an empty result

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I have a problem. I've created a new class. I require this class in my `functions.php` and then I create a new object from the class `new Test();`. So far so good.

In my constructor I then have the following:

```
public function __construct() {
    error_log( get_query_var( 'view-order' ) );
    $this->register();
}
```

The problem is that get_query_var returns an empty result. I actually expect the order number of a WooCommerce order here.

How can this be?

**Update:**
When I do this inside a template for example, it works fine. Strange....

Comment: that depends on which page you are calling this...

Comment: On the correct one (View order page). I'm not that stupid.

Comment: get_query_var() is looking for a global value. This value may not yet be installed when you call your constructor. But can be installed, when you call this in template

Comment: you should really help us out here.. you're question is not enough... if you call `new Test();` inside the `functions.php` then seems to me `'view-order'` is not yet available.. I suggest you use some action hook. That, I do not know if you're doing it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try code below:

```
// function php

class Test {

    public function __construct()
    {
        add_action( 'template_redirect', [ $this, 'get_order_id' ] );
    }

    public function get_order_id()
    {
        if ( is_view_order_page() ) {
            $order_id = wc_clean( get_query_var('view-order') );
        }
    }
}

new Test();
```

Comment: Seems to be working with the template redirect :) Nice!